# why does this error occur [JAVA]

Tags: java

This code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Fix 
{   
   int Search(int arr[], int x,int n)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
          if (arr[i] == x)
             return i;
        return 0;
    }

    void Func(int in[], int pre[], int n)
    {
        int root=Search(in,pre[0],n); 

         if (root != 0)
                Func(in,pre+1, root); //error 

           if (root != n-1)
             Func(in+root+1, pre+root+1, n-root-1); //error

       System.out.print(pre[0]+" ");
    }
 }
```

Error point is:

> Func(in,pre+1, root);

and

> Func(in+root+1, pre+root+1, n-root-1);

Why does this occur? In C++, this error does not happened.

[image]

Comment: Why do you think you can add an integer array to an integer?

Comment: Java doesn't have pointer arithmetic

Comment: What MadProgrammer said.

Comment: how to print array address in java ??

Comment: @신한강 Array.toString();

Answer (score 0):

Java is not C++. So you cannot do stuff in Java using syntax of C++.

In Java, you cannot use `+` on arrays and int. So `pre + 1` will fail. Also, it does not make any sense to increment an array by 1.

The second error is basically the same thing, **It just makes no sense whatsoever to increase an array by 1**.

I think you want to increase the array pointer by one, am I right? If you want to do that, *use another language*! We do not have pointers in Java! They just do not exist! Neither pointers nor `goto`s exist in Java because Sun probably thought they are PURE EVIL.

There is a (bad) workaround. Use C#! C# have this unsafe keyword that can create an unsafe context:

```
unsafe {

}
```

In the unsafe context, you can use pointers, `stackalloc` and lots more "unsafe" stuff. However, unsafe contexts are very rare in C#, don't use them unless you have to!